# upgrade from 9.4 to 9.6 using pg_upgrade fails

Tags: postgresql, windows, upgrade

I'm using pg_upgrade to upgrade postgresql from 9.4 to 9.6.Both versions are installed on windows server 2016.I followed the steps described in https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgupgrade.html. Just as following:

```
RUNAS /USER:postgres "CMD.EXE"
SET PATH=%Path%;D:\Program Files\Postresql 9.6\bin;
D:\Program Files\Postresql 9.6\bin>pg_upgrade.exe --old-datadir "D:/Program Files/Postgresql/data" --new-datadir "D:/Program Files/Postresql 9.6/data" --old-bindir "D:/Program Files/Postgresql/bin" --new-bindir "D:/Program Files/Postresql 9.6/bin"
```

After run I got this

```
check for "D:/Program Files/Postgresql/data/base" failed: No such file or directory
Failure, exiting
```

I've checked,the directory exists and "postgres" have all previliges. I'm new to postgresql,pls tell me how could I solve this.

Comment: "*No such file or directory*" is pretty obvious - you didn't run `initdb` to create the new data directory. But you shouldn't store the data directory in `Program Files` to begin with. That directory is highly restricted for a reason, the data directory should be outside of that.

Comment: I used the windows installer, it initialize the new PostgreSQL cluster automatically. And I can find the data/base directory in both versions.

Comment: The user that executed `pg_upgrade` does not have the required permissions on the directory (or one of its parents).

Comment: "I've checked,the directory exists and "postgres" have all previliges"  What files are in that directory?

Comment: the user executing pg_upgrade has all permissions on the directory and parent directory;